# "Multiple ContextLoader* definitions error" occurred while using my own custom ContextLoaderListener

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application, and use the embedded jetty container, with no `web.xml` file.
I have a custom `ContextLoaderLister` class, which is a sub-class of default `Spring ContextLoaderListener`:

```
public class MyContextListener extends org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
```

and register it as below:

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfiguration {
  @Bean
  public ServletContextListener listener(){
    return new ContextDestroyListener();
  }
}
```

But while start the container, get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot initialize context because there is already a root application context present - check whether you have multiple ContextLoader* definitions in your web.xml!
```

I just want to use the custom `ContextLoaderListener`, rather than the default `ContextLoaderListener`. But get this error. It seems when I use the `@Bean` annotation to register a `ContextLoaderListener`, the default `Spring ContextLoaderListener` is still being used, so they are 2 `ContextLoader` in `ApplicationContext`, which cause this error.
I want to know what should I do, if I want to register my own `ContextLoaderListener`, and let Sprint not to add the default one automatically.

Comment: Any solution found for this , i have same issue now, and below answer is not working

Answer (score 0):

You can make your configuration extend `SpringBootServletInitializer` and then override `onStartup` method:

```
public class MyApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        super.onStartup(servletContext);
        servletContext.addListener(new MyContextListener());
    }

}
```

Please be aware that this listener will not get `contextInitialized` event since context is already initialized in this moment.

Comment: This solution did not work,i have the same issue now, any other solution ?